# How to make Equations exceeds one column from the IEEE template?

Tags: equations, line-breaking, ieeetran, multline

Equation exceeds one column of IEEE pattern in LaTeX how should I correct it? Please help, the code is attached herewith.

```
H_{LOS}(0;T_i,R_j) =
\frac{(m+1)A_p}{2\pi d_{ij}^{m+3}}\left\{
\left[x_j^R-x_i^T,y_j^R-y_i^T,-\triangle h_{ij}\right]
\cdot \left[\sin \left(\beta_i\right)\cos\left(\alpha_i\right),
\sin \left(\beta_i\right)\sin\left(\alpha_i\right),
-\cos\left(\beta_i\right)\right]\right\}^m \times 
\left\{\left[x_i^T-x_j^R,y_i^T-y_j^R, -h_{ij}\right]\cdot 
\left[\sin \left(\beta_j\right)\cos\left(\alpha_j\right),
\sin \left(\beta_j\right)\sin\left(\alpha_j\right),
-\cos\left(\beta_j\right)\right]\right\}G
\left(\theta_{ij}^{tilt}\right)rect\left(\frac{\theta_{ij}^{tilt}}{\Theta}\right)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please edit your question to have a minimal, but working (i.e. compileable) example. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/237192.

Comment: see `align` and related envrironments from `amsmath` to linebreak equations